# mathディレクティブをつかって数式内で日本語を使用する方法

Tags: sphinx

Sphinxで数式内で日本語を使いたいと思っているのですが、上手くできず困っています。
webで検索すると、\mboxを使用することで、数式内で日本語が使用できるとあったのですが、Sphinxではエラーが出てしまい、日本語が使用できません。
日本語無しの数式が出力されることは確認しています。

単純に下記のようにしてもエラーとなってしまいます。

```
.. math::

    \mbox{日本語}
```

環境はmacOS Sierra,python 3.5.2,sphinx 1.4.1,MacTex 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

前提の確認です

- レンダリングには `sphinx.ext.imgmath` を使っていますか？
- 出力はHTMLですか？
- 出力しようとした数式のテキストと、エラーログを添付してください

sphinx.ext.imgmath は dvipng を使って数式をレンダリングします。
しかし、[dvipngは日本語を扱えない](https://yutarine.blogspot.jp/2009/07/latex-dvipng.html)ようです。

代わりに `sphinx.ext.mathjax` を使ってみて下さい。

Comment: ご推察の通りでした。レンダリングにはsphinx.ext.imgmathを使用し、出力はHTMLを指定していました。sphinx.ext.mathjaxを使用したところ、日本語の出力ができるようになりました。ありがとうございます。